Integrating Third-Party Token-Based Authentication before calling Third party APIs
I am currently using Java 21 along with the latest Spring Security version 3.2.2.
I have a requirement to call a third-party URL using this request body to obtain an access token, also handling token renewal, and injecting this token into the RestTemplate for subsequent API calls..
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://example.org/api/Login' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "userId": "user",
  "password": "password"
} '

the response of this end point is in the form
{
  "status": "true",
  "token": "token_sample",
  "email": "test@test.com"
}

I have implemented a class that retrieves the token and injects it into the RestTemplate.
My question is: Is there a better way to achieve this using Spring Security while utilizing the latest Spring features , instead of handling the token and checking for expiration explicity? Please guide.
@Component
public class abcAuthenticationTokenProvider {

    @Value("${abc.url}/Login")
    private String loginUrl;

    @Value("${abc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${abc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${abc.tokenExpirationInterval}")
    private Long tokenExpirationInterval;

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private LocalDateTime tokenIssueTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    private String token = null;

    public abcAuthenticationTokenProvider(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String getBearerToken() {
        // If no token exists, authenticate for the first time
        if (token == null) {
            authenticate();
        } else if (tokenExpirationInterval != null && isTokenExpired()) {
            authenticate();
        }
        return token;
    }

    private void authenticate() throws AuthenticationException {

        var loginRequest = new abcLoginRequest(username, password);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<abcLoginRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(loginRequest, headers);
        ResponseEntity<abcLoginResponse> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.exchange(
                        loginUrl,
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        request,
                        abcLoginResponse.class);

        var response = responseEntity.getBody();
        if (response != null && response.status().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            this.token = response.token();
            this.tokenIssueTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Login to abc failed");
        }
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired() {
        // Calculate the time difference in seconds between now and when the token was issued
        long secondsSinceIssued = java.time.Duration.between(tokenIssueTime, LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds();
        return secondsSinceIssued >= tokenExpirationInterval;
    }


    private record abcLoginRequest(String userId, String password) {
    }

    private record abcLoginResponse(String status, String token) {
    }
}

......
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Value("${abc.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${abc.connection.timeout}")
    private long connectionTimeout;

    @Value("${abc.read.timeout}")
    private long readTimeout;

    @Autowired
    private abcAuthenticationTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate abcRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder
                .rootUri(url)
                .interceptors((request, body, execution) -> {
                    String token = tokenProvider.getBearerToken();

                    if (token != null) {
                        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
                        headers.setBearerAuth(token);
                    }
                    return execution.execute(request, body);
                })
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectionTimeout))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeout))
                .build();
    }

}


you start by not using RestTemplate, and instead use Webclient

Or you can use RestClient If you don't want to go in reactive approach.
